# How to count running time of merge-sort?

Tags: function, sorting, count, mergesort, operation

I've been having a little trouble figuring out how to calculate the time complexity for merge-sorting this series of numbers: 44, 112, 178, 48, 10, 22, 28, 186, 66, 86, 128, 82, 168. The numbers should end up in ascending order.

I'm not sure if this will help or not, but here's a diagram showing the merge-sorting function being run on a different set of numbers: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e6/Merge_sort_algorithm_diagram.svg/300px-Merge_sort_algorithm_diagram.svg.png

Comment: Are you looking for time complexity or the actual running time of the algorithm on your machine? If it's the latter you're looking for, then save the time right before sorting, then get the time after sorting. With those, simply subtract the starting time from the ending time and you have your time it took to perform the sort. If time complexity is what you're interested in, then I'd suggest reading up on Big-O notation and answering you're own question that way.

Comment: Oops, yes, I'm trying to calculate the time complexity

Comment: My issue isn't so much that I don't know what time complexity is, but that I don't know how to relate it to this particular scenario.

Comment: Given a specific array, I assume that you're trying to count the number of comparisons being made?